# Python/Selenium Webdriver: Adding new input text

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am using the python3 unittest library with selenium webdriver. I have the exisiting already question in my application. I am trying to add another question but when I am trying to insert text into text field in my new question - it changes text in my existing question instead of the new one...
I am using:

```
wd.find_element_by_id("id_question-1-title").click()
wd.find_element_by_id("id_question-1-title").clear()
wd.find_element_by_id("id_question-1-title").send_keys("ABC")
```

But this solution requires changing id everytime I run code into id_question-2-title, id_question-3-title etc

Comment: I'm assuming that the new question contains 1 in the ID and the existing question moves to 2?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check how many questions you have and give the index accordingly

```
questions = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="id_question-1-title"]')
index = len(questions)

wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').click()
wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').clear()
wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').send_keys("ABC")
```

Answer (score 0):

Guy, thank you very much! I just added str to len(questions) because it required str insted of int

```
questions = wd.find_elements_by_css_selector('[id*="id_question-1-title"]')
index = str(len(questions))
wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').click()
wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').clear()
wd.find_element_by_id('id_question-' + index + '-title').send_keys("ABC")
```